# Send SSH commands from AWS Lambda (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to create a function in AWS Lambda Nodejs that can send some SSH commands to a linux machine. Is it possible?

I know there are some nodejs modules to do this, but AWS Lambda Nodejs doesn't have them, and I don't want to involve any EC2 to this Lambda.

I just want to know how can I, from AWS Lambda function, execute some commands in a linux machine, either by SSH or some other methods that I couldn't think of.

Comment: Can you do a REST call to the other server to accomplish what you want?

Comment: or, maybe you can invoke the shell using something like this? https://dzone.com/articles/execute-unix-command-nodejs but will Lambda even allow you to ssh would be an interesting question to answer

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, however just wanted to mention, Lambda currently does not have the ability to interact with any resources behind a VPC.  Check out this project, it might prove useful? https://alestic.com/2014/11/aws-lambda-environment/

Comment: Thanks guy, but I think I'll just use my home server API for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of options: You can popen ssh from Python, use a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh from nodejs, etc.

Comment: This question is titlled "Send SSH commands from AWS Lambda (NodeJS)". Whereas `simple-ssh` package allows interacting with the `ssh` executable on your system via nodejs. It is NOT enough to run ssh on lambda. (Because AWS Lambda machine doesn't have `ssh` executable installed). Thus this as accepted answer is a bit misleading as it doesn't solve core OPs problem

Answer (score 1):

This post is relatively old now but for whoever finds this, AWS made a blog post describing mostly what you're looking for: https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/compute/scheduling-ssh-jobs-using-aws-lambda/

Obviously the AWS blog post describes how to use this for AWS Services but the example still stands using python.

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm this is working on lambda with Alexa and simple-ssh. Couple things of note: ssh.on("close" is required because otherwise the lambda function will shut down before the SSH command is finished working. (Lambda shuts down on alexa.execute call.)

This is one of the top Google results for "ssh lambda aws" so I'm posting this here in hopes of saving some time for others that need to do this.

Working example: https://github.com/PockyBum522/alexa_nodejs_send_ssh_commands_lambda

```
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');
var Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");

var ssh = new SSH({
    host: 'yourserver.com',
    user: 'username',
    key: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEApQtRxugrDMU8YNBy2j2Lyk6yAxMSKaiusrNUamXKLxFvdlZ1
6HCN+jjaE7q8OYFEmq9l2B5U8GCYMFldXWBxIv7fvRWyi1ZTw3olaZ8DmGYwPKLM
TOQ3MOm/zcJZbiTY1/cx2CW6NupPX78O42hLKM2iJwp6epgxC5t2Vw==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);

    ssh.on("close", function () {alexa.execute()});
    ssh
        .exec('nohup /home/username/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &', {  // Nohup runs script in BG, > /dev/null redirects output. & also runs in BG. Trying to keep things fast to make alexa response time good.
            out: console.log.bind(console)
        })
        .exec('exit', {                                               // Also for trying to keep things fast.
            out: console.log.bind(console)
        }).start(); 
};

var handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function(){
        this.emit(':tell', 'Now opening the garage door.'); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Not sure why this have been downvoted. This is the correct answer! And it's still working in 2019